# spring using security:authentication principal.username in link

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Ok this should be an easy one

In the header.jspx file i would like to have a link that will lead the authenticated user to their userpage.

This is what i am using to retrieve the username:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

This is what i want to put it in:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/dealclick/users/username_here" > My account </a>
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried

```
<c:set var="username">
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> 
</c:set>
```

and then use

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/dealclick/users/${username}" > My account </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace it in:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/dealclick/users/<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>" > My account </a>
```